# How to dynamically create operators with different params

Tags: airflow

I have the following code:

```
def chunck_import(**kwargs):
    ...
    logging.info('Number of pages required is: {0}'.format(num_pages))
    for i in range(1, num_pages + 1):
        ...
        parameter_where = 'where orders_id between {0} and {1}'.format(start,end)
        logging.info(parameter_where)

chunck_import_op = PythonOperator(
    task_id='chunck_import',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=chunck_import,
    dag=dag)


start_task_op >> ... >>  chunck_import_op
```

This operator create multiple `WHERE` statements:

```
INFO - From 7557920 to 7793493
INFO - Number of pages required is: 4
where orders_id between 7607920 and 7657920
where orders_id between 7657921 and 7707920
where orders_id between 7707921 and 7757920
where orders_id between 7757921 and 7793493
```

Now, I have a `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` as follows:

```
import_orders_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import_orders',
    ...
    sql = 'select * from orders {{ params.where_cluster }}',
    params={'where_cluster': parameter_where},
    dag=dag)
```

The `chunck_import_op` knows the number of times I need to call the `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`   - `num_pages` It also create the string that I need to pass as parameter-  `parameter_where`

My issue is how to dynamically create the `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` according to `num_pages` and pass the `parameter_where` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would subclass [`MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py) to customize the query and override the execute steps to produce a paged query as per a page size parameter passed to the operator. This is some extra work, but is recommended over the other options here.

You cannot however have a `PythonOperator`, or any operator, modify the DAG (and have it recognized and scheduled). The most it could do is one of:

1. After building the where clause, construct a `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` with the clause and call execute on it right within the `PythonOperator`. This will work, and you will see log messages from the `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` right in the `PythonOperator`'s logs.
2. Use the `PythonOperator` or `TriggerDagRunOperator` to trigger another DAG with just the `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` passing in the clause as a parameter, or pushing it to XCOM for that DAG first. That other DAG should probably have a Schedule set to `@None`. This will make following up the logs a little harder, but it could run the DAGs in parallel.

If it were my DAG, I think my approach instead (if not subclassing) would be to always process in 1 to X pages. Let's propose your DAG should handle a maximum X pages of results where X is 10 for example. Then define 10 branches off `chunck_import_op`'s parent. You won't need `chunck_import_op` or the callable.

- Each branch will start with a `ShortCircuitOperator` which calls the same callable with different `offset` arguments (0 through 9). This callable will check if `offset * page_size` is greater than `end`, if so it returns `False`, skipping its downstream operators. Otherwise it'll push into xcom a valid query with the range based on the offset and return `True` to run them.
- Each branch continues with a `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` which has the query set as `{{ ti.xcom_pull('<ShortCircuitOperator_N>') }}` where the string is the name of the preceding `ShortCircuitOperator`.
- If you need other operators after the `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`s first add a `DummyOperator` as a child of all of these `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`s, and make the `trigger_rule` `ALL_DONE`, then add the other operators as children of that one.

This way you can run 1 to 10 paged queries if necessary. They might run in parallel though, I don't think that's a potential problem though, just consider it.

Comment: My problem with your segguestion (regarding the If it were my DAG) that it assumes that I know the start for doing the start + offset * page size. I have no access to the start as it's calculated with an earlier task.

Comment: @Programmer120 well I mean, let's say there's 3 branches. They start with `ShortCircuitOperator` that has a `param` with a `page` that is 0, 1 or 2. Each op fetches the start calculated by the previous task, its start will be `fetched_start+page*page_size` which should be less than `end` that you must be fetching from somewhere too.

Comment: The end is known I have it stored in a variable before the DAG started so I can read it at start. The end is like a hard-codded value. My problem is with the start. I understand your calculation but what I still don't understand is where do you get the first fetched_start for the first page. It is calculated in a task in the same DAG. this is my whole problem :\

Comment: @Programmer120 you didn't show in your question where you got the start either but the output shows you did `INFO - From 7557920 to 7793493`. Either each of the `ShortCircuitOperators` have do include the code to get it, or If it's in `chunk_import` keep that part of the operator and, if not redundant, push that to xcom, then have each of the `ShortCircuitOperators` use it by pulling from the same task output.

Comment: chunck_import is what calculates the start till the end. I printed it because I didn't know how to continue. I need somehow to replace the print with the actual execution of the import of records.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow provides the [XComs mechanism](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms) for the tasks (operators) to communicate among themselves. In your concrete scenario, the `chunck_import` task can precompute all where clauses first and push them into an XCom; then the `import_orders` task can pull the XCom, read all where clauses, and use them as needed.

If this mechanism does not work for your application logic then please amend your question and explain why not.

Comment: `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` execute a single query. if I have 5 `where_cluster` I need 5 queries meaning I need 5 `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`. This is why I wrote that I need to dynamically create `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` operators.